# Not all columns in the dataframe are filling with funtions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a functions which takes column, group it by list of other columns and then return this column with values NaN filled with median value of certain column.
When i first check NaN values in column 'Age', it shows me that there are 177 NaN values, but after function work it shows be that such values are 49. What may be cause? There should be 0 columns

```
def fill_na(df, missing_value_col, grouping_col):
  values = df.groupby([i for i in grouping_col])[missing_value_col].median()
  df.set_index(grouping_col, inplace=True)
  df[missing_value_col].fillna(values, inplace=True)
  df.reset_index(grouping_col, inplace=True)

  return df
```

fill_na(titset, 'Age', ['Fare','Pclass'])

```
import pandas as pd
months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr']
sales = {
'revenue':     [100, 200, None, None],
'items_sold':  [23, 43, 55, 65],
'new_clients': [10, 20, 30, 40]
}
sales_df = pd.DataFrame(data=sales, index=months)
sales_df
```

Comment: `[i for i in grouping_col]` is an odd choice if `grouping_col` is already a list. No need for that.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any use in the two `df.set_index` calls, since I don't see the index being used.

Comment: An example small dataframe before and after would help; I think this can be solved much simpler.

Comment: edited in quesiton

Answer (score 0):

Probable cause: some of your groups contain only NaN values for the 'Age', so the median age for those groups is NaN and you are filling the NaN values with NaN.

You should check if your `values` dataframe contains NaN.

Comment: yes, that really was a problem